# Run a script which is waiting for signal and is polling a ressource

Tags: php, python, daemon

I'm trying a create a script (in preference in PHP but Python should be fine too) which have the following behaviour :

We register a call back function which should start as soon as we receive a signal with an argument. Then, we create an infinite loop (this script should never stop!) to poll a webservice with a session (we got a logout very 15 minutes and we didn't want to be disconnected!).

Here is a the behaviour in pseudo-code :

```
function CALLBACK($arguments)
{
    CURL(URL, {ARGUMENTS : $arguments});
}
add_handler(SIGNAL, ARGUMENTS, CALLBACK);

$last_poll = time();
while(true)
{
    if (time() - $last_poll > 600)
    {
        CURL(URL_TO_POLL);
        $last_poll = time();
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe its help you.
Gearman provides a generic application framework to farm out work to other machines or processes that are better suited to do the work. It allows you to do work in parallel, to load balance processing, and to call functions between languages. It can be used in a variety of applications, from high-availability web sites to the transport of database replication events. In other words, it is the nervous system for how distributed processing communicates. A few strong points about Gearman:

more on offical site http://gearman.org/

Comment: I've never try Gearman, but I think it can't execute an infinite loop waiting to receive a signal with some arguments... I really want a daemon which is polling a service every 10 minutes and is waiting to handle a signal to lauch a function.

Comment: @Kevin also you can look at [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html).